# How to indicate a Male choice / Female choice of identical content

Tags: interaction-design, mobile-application, gender

I'm working on an app that will be used for therapeutic purposes.

Some of the excercises include audio tracks, and those audio tracks have been recorded twice (one with a male's voice and one with a female's)

I originally only had the record show once (kicking off the male voice by default) and allowed the user to select the female voice after the track began playing. This (for obvious reasons) was a bad design.

I've now changed it to show both records at the same time, and allow the user to select either the female voice or the male voice right from the start.

Now I'm struggling with the UX design on how to best display to the user exactly what's what.

Here's a screenshot of our navigation drawer.
*Notice the duplicate "Abdominal Breathing Exerciser" entries. One is [M] and one is [F]*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than allowing the user to select male or female voice at a track level, why not allow them to set it once for the whole application?

If you are choosing a default for this, I think it makes more sense to have a female voice as the default, as it is commonly understood that people of both sexes respond better to female voices (hence the female Siri, the default voice in Microsoft speech is female, and every elevator with a voice announcing floors).

Comment: Sat navs too are usually female are they not ?

Comment: @ColinSharpe ah yes, you are right.

Comment: A global setting isn't a bad idea. My first thought to solving this problem was changing the hue of the record based on gender (pink/blue/black) where black is "neutral" when there isn't multiple recordings specified.

Answer (score 0):

Modal through into a view that allows you to pick male or female voice. Keep a button in the listening view so that they can freely change the voice whenever they want to.

As @franchesca said, use female as a default because both sexes respond better to female voices.

Comment: Sending the user to a separate view was our original implementation. What I'm trying to do is get the app "out of the way" by removing the need for additional touches (clicks)